# Ubuntu 18.04 Hardware RAID size discrepencies

Tags: 18.04, raid

I had a 4 x 4TB Hardware RAID 5 (Adaptec ASR7805) set up on an HP ML110 with a reported 11TB available capacity. I started to run low on space so I migrated the RAID array across to a HP ML330 chassis, giving me the ability to add an additional 4 x 4TB drives into the RAID array.

This all worked out a treat with a reported 26.7TB available capacity in the RAID configuration utility and also by running arcconf getconfig 1 ld. However when I run either df -h or lsblk these display 11TB of available.

I have attached some pictures of the commands outputs for reference, any ideas why this is and will it cause any confusion between the OS and RAID controller when I go over 11TB?

Thanks in advance
Phill

[arcconf getconfig 1 ld](https://i.stack.imgur.com/terIu.jpg)
[df - h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ffwhf.jpg)
[lsblk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H76Ps.jpg)

Comment: Ubuntu 18?    Ubuntu desktop and server releases have a *yy.mm* format, and whilst specialist snap based releases like Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT appliances do use a *yy* format there are none titled just Ubuntu 18.  Please clarify your release as there is no Ubuntu 18, and your title implies a different Ubuntu product to your tagged product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RAID is now 26.7 TB large, but did you also resize the filesystem on that RAID?

What filesystem type are you using? Ext4? XFS? Btrfs? Something else?

Comment: I am using ext4 filesystem and didn't resize the file system after the RAID had rebuilt.

Comment: fdisk -l is reporting 25.5TB size, so does this mean that the partition size is correct I now just need to extend the file system?

What would be the best method to extend the filesystem size? I can unmount to work on if necessary.

Comment: Use `resize2fs` (package _e2fsprogs_). Maybe even the graphical `gparted` can do that for you (it will also use `resize2fs` internally).

Comment: Thanks HuHa.

resize2fs has resized the file system and I'm now seeing 26TB when I run df -h and lsblk.

The only additionally task that was needed was to convert the filesystem to 64bit.

Thanks for your advise, I can now resume my NAS backup.